# AWS DynamoDB Missing credentials in config in local dev environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My colleague successfully perform the following code showing the table without setting the credentials in local environment, but when i conduct it it shows such error on my local machine. Please help.

Please find my codes below:

Controller:

```
    AWS.config.update({
        region: 'localhost',
        endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8008'),
    })
    var params = {
        TableName: 'history',
        KeySchema: [{
            AttributeName: 'b_id',
            KeyType: 'HASH'
        },{
            AttributeName: 'e_id',
            KeyType: 'RANGE'
        }],
        AttributeDefinitions: [{
            AttributeName: 'b_id',
            AttributeType: 'S',
        },{
            AttributeName: 'e_id',
            AttributeType: 'N',
        }],
        ProvisionedThroughput: { // required provisioned throughput for the table
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1, 
        },
    }
    response.implicitEnd = false
    AWS.query('history',params, function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        else  response.json(data)
    })
```

Error Message:

> { Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80 - Local () at
>   Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at _exceptionWithHostPort
>   (util.js:1044:20) at internalConnect (net.js:971:16) at net.js:1065:9
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7) at
>   process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
>   message: 'Missing credentials in config', code: 'CredentialsError',
>   errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH', syscall: 'connect', address: '169.254.169.254',
>   port: 80, time: 2018-04-30T04:34:53.218Z, originalError: { message:
>   'Could not load credentials from any providers', code:
>   'CredentialsError', errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH', syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '169.254.169.254', port: 80, time: 2018-04-30T04:34:53.218Z,
>   originalError: { code: 'EHOSTUNREACH', errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH', syscall:
>   'connect', address: '169.254.169.254', port: 80, message: 'connect
>   EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80 - Local ()' } } }

```
> which python 
/usr/bin/python

> pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (10.0.1)
metplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.

> pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

> python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Comment: `Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80` is a failure to connect to the EC2 instance metadata service, which is expected since you are not running this code inside EC2.  The most likely explanation is that your colleague does indeed have credentials configured in their local environment.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Michael-sqlbot, however how do i configure my local environment? is it like what Siu's answer and comments stated below? I failed to execute the last step because I couldn't find my .bash_profile, even after i `touch` it it still doesnt work (sorry for my lack of bash knowledge)

Comment: it may also be just `.profile`.  If you have sudo access, you can `sudo pip install awscli` and you don't have to redefine the path.

Comment: ya i think i installed it but it doesn't work still, error message remains: `awc: command not found`

Comment: Also there isn't any `.profile` either

Comment: I show a bit more details on the process, please help @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Stu informs about the configuration, just to hope people encounter the same as what I did trying to put it to work on localhost. after typing awscli `aws configure`, as it asked you for the access ID and secret access ID, you have to at least type in something to make it work (cannot leave it blank) so that it will create config files at `~/.aws` directory, where in my case I simply just typed in `a` for both entry, then `region:localhost` and `output:json` though i think region is really just up to you. Please help to refine my answer, at least this works out for me allowing me to continue using DynamoDB on local machine

Comment: You can also set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables to achieve the same effect. Useful if you're working in Docker and want to inject the values for test or production.

Answer (score 18):

This is what's working for me

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'xxxx',
  secretAccessKey: 'xxxx',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
});

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB()
const dynamoDbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

The accessKeyId and secretAccessKey does not need to be real values.

Comment: Thanks for your response @roxxypoxxy, I guess we are on the same track!

Comment: ...and it cannot be an empty string, e.g.: `accessKeyId: ''` and/or `secretAccessKey: ''`

Answer (score 4):

Once configured AWS credentials are stored in a local configuration file. For windows the file can be found at

```
%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials
```

For linux the file can be found at

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

You need to have this file available. Install AWS CLI. Then to configure this file open a command line on your local machine and enter

```
aws configure
```

Details on the CLI setup are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html). Details of the credentials file are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input, i am using macOS and trying to install awscli in the machine but stuck at the point where after i install awsli by executing the cli: `pip install awscli --upgrade --user` and `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` , aws command still not found

Comment: Open a new terminal or execute source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path

Comment: it says no such file or directory

Comment: I dont see the bash_profile in the directory but only `.bash_history` and `.bash_sessions`

Comment: I show a bit more details in the question at the end, please help thanks!